# Working on Twilio iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, twilio

Is anybody here who have ever worked on [Twilio iOS SDK Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client).

Actually i am running one of the Twilio SDK Examaples. and i am getting weired Error. 
i put my auth.php and Helper Libraries and basic-call.pnh files onto my Local Server but when i tried to connect it through my application from iPhone it gives me the following error:

```
 2012-01-24 14:11:26.694 HelloMonkey[5346:7403] Error establishing connection due to error: Status Code domain: TwilioHTTPErrorDomain code: 487
 2012-01-24 14:11:29.677 HelloMonkey[5346:7403] Error establishing connection due to error: Status Code domain: TwilioHTTPErrorDomain code: 408
```

These errors occurs after 5 - 10 minutes after my connection successful. 
Also i am not hearing any response from basic-call.php.

My Basic call.php has simple code that says "Welcome to Twilio Client". But its not saying it.
Can any body help.

Thnaks

Comment: I'll check with the right team in the morning, but did you receive any errors in the debugger? twilio.com/user/account/debugger. If you did not have any errors there, it's probable that your client was not connecting successfully to the Twilio API from your iPhone.

Comment: i dont know about the errors in debugger since i am new in twilio SDK. i just followed the Start Guide in the SDK and using the HelloMonkey1.0 Code for this. and getting the above mentioned errors :(

Comment: Just go to www.twilio.com/user/account/debugger, and see if there are any errors corresponding to the time you tried the app on your iOS SDK. If not, you are probably getting a connection error.

Comment: 404 for www.twilio.com/user/account/debugger

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Client Mobile suffered a short outage around the time that your question was asked. Can you please try running your code again and see if you get the same error?

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Check out whether the VoiceURL in your application setting page of Twilio points to basic-call.php.Whatever URL mentioned under VoiceURL only twilio attempts to call.